# eclipse - What are facets and what is their purpose?

Tags: eclipse, facet

I just starting out with Maven in Eclipse. Can someone tell me what are project facets and why do we need them ?

Also in my project why do I have only facets regarding JavaServerFaces ? What about stuff like Spring and Hibernate and Struts ? Where are the facets for them ?

Why can't settings be changed in the facets ? I can't change my java version to 1.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809918/what-is-facet-in-javaee