# How can I chose a specific version of Java EE in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

It's my first day with Java EE and I would like to understand:

How I can set up a Java EE 7 project? and where can I check what Java EE version I am actually using?

I downloaded the latest Eclipse for Java EE Developers (Neon) and am now trying to understand how all these parts fit together.

I ended up downloading [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 Web Profile SDK Update 3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eesdk-419427.html) as well as a Shell file to install [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 7 SDK Update 3](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eesdk-419427.html).

I know there is a lot of instructions provided but I would just like to set up my Eclipse environment.

Happy for any help or resource!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change JDK version for an Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588537/how-to-change-jdk-version-for-an-eclipse-project)

Comment: @clinomaniac they are asking about Java EE, which is different from Java SE (i.e. a JDK) version

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial http://www.edu4java.com/en/servlet/servlet4.html it's old but it basically the same thing

- You have to create a new project (Dynamic Web Project)
- The versions of the Facets you choose will determine which Java EE spec version it aligns with
- Choose your application server (I personally recommend Wildfly http://wildfly.org/, but the built-in Java EE Preview Server can run Servlets on its own)

And you are ready to go !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this Link said nothing about Facets or how to set a specific JavaEE version. I am not sure what facets are as well? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809918/what-is-facet-in-javaee) suggests it is a JSF. I found on a tutorial about Arquillian [link](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/?utm_source=cta) explains that you can set the Java EE version via Maven dependency `<artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>`.